# Tag synonym suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I thought now might be a good opportunity to have a thread specifically for tag synonym suggestions (from users who have less than the required rep for doing such themselves).

Post suggestions that you see fit as answers, and upvotes and downvotes will determine the community's reaction. 3-5 upvotes generally warrants a successful suggestions.

Comment: While this post may have made sense in the early days of (private) beta, I don't think it makes sense any more to add new synonym suggestions here as answers. That only serves to bury the suggestions and stifle discussion. Other recent synonym suggestions have done quite well in their own post. I have VtCed this post as 'Too Broad'.

Answer (score 9):

Synonym proposal: [augustine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augustine) (7 questions), [st-augustine-of-hippo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/st-augustine-of-hippo) (2 questions), [augustine-of-hippo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augustine-of-hippo) (2 questions).

Based on the question count, [augustine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augustine) seems a good candidate for the authoritative name.

([wax eagle](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/wax-eagle) caught the first tag; I did not notice that duplicate when browsing tags.)

Comment: One of the "of Hippo" tags might be better for authoritative as it's specific.

Comment: I agree with Ryan, and I prefer the [tag:augustine-of-hippo] version without the `st-` part mostly to reduce the overall level of clutter.

Comment: Are there other Augustines of sufficient significance in Christianity that they would get a tag? In *theory*, the wiki summary could provide some disambiguation. If the other two became *synonyms* (not deleted), then taggers could use them (they would be automatically converted to the smaller form). Question count and length favor the "bare" 'augustine', but I can sympathize with the desire for the more formal and precise 'augustine-of-hippo' being the primary tag.

Comment: [Augustine of Canterbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Canterbury), perhaps?

Comment: @RyanFrame Interesting. Now I may have to ask "What is the standard for unambiguous base tag naming?"

Answer (score 5):

I suggest making [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) and [bible-translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-translation) synonyms.

There is [one question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/hebrew-ot-translation-to-greek-nt) which deals with translation from the Old Testament to the New Testament, but every other question with either tag covers translation to English. I am not certain what to do with that question.

Perhaps the problem is that people are using [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) when [bible-translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible-translation) should be applied. In that case, we should retag the other seven [translation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) questions before the problem becomes too widespread.

Answer (score 4):

I just made an [aliens](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag without realising there's an [extra-terrestrial-life](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extra-terrestrial-life) tag. They should be synonyms. Personally I think aliens is better - it's shorter and a more common term.

Answer (score 3):

proposal: 'apostle-john' should be a synonym of 'john-apostle' (based on previous handling of 'paul-apostle' (and, incidentally, question count)

Answer (score 2):

Should [adam](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam) be a synonym for [adam-and-eve](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam-and-eve)? (There is no 'eve' tag.)

Several questions using [adam](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam) actually seem to be a *better* fit for [adam-and-eve](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam-and-eve), e.g.:

- [Did God create Adam and Eve with free will and knowledge of right and wrong (good and evil)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16019/did-god-create-adam-and-eve-with-free-will-and-knowledge-of-right-and-wrong-goo)
- [Why did the devil tempt Eve first?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/why-did-the-devil-tempt-eve-first)
- [Why is it a sin to eat an apple?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/why-is-it-a-sin-to-eat-an-apple)

[Why is the curse of original sin not specific to humans?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16560/why-is-the-curse-of-original-sin-not-specific-to-humans) is actually tagged with *both*.

On the other hand, some questions are somewhat Adam-specific.

Comment: lol is there a lilith tag?

Answer (score 1):

[liturgy-of-the-hours](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liturgy-of-the-hours) should be the canonical tag for [breviary](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breviary), [divine-office](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divine-office) and maybe [book-of-common-prayer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-common-prayer) although that may be confused with the Anglican prayer book.

Comment: This would make sense except we don't seem to be getting any questions with any of these tags, so synonyms aren't really an issue yet. Maybe we should ask some!

Answer (score 1):

Should [prophecy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophecy) (wiki summary: "the communication of messages directly received from God, either in biblical or modern times.") and [special-revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-revelation) (no wiki summary) be synonyms?

If so, the question count would favor [prophecy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophecy) being the primary tag, but an emphasis on academic tone *might* prefer [special-revelation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-revelation).

Comment: What does [tag:special-revelation] mean, is that a Protestant term?  Fred's question looks like it might almost mean what Catholics would call Private Revelation (outside the Bible), but Caleb's question definitely isn't talking about that

Comment: @PeterTurner The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_revelation) seems decent. Basically, special revelation is supernatural revelation as distinct from the general revelation of creation (which would include conscience). Wikipedia indicates that it is primarily an "evangelical" term.

Comment: This is an interesting one, as a Charismatic I'm personally for viewing them as synonymous, but I think there are certain schools of Cessationist thought that wish to preserve a distinction between them.

Answer (score 1):

Both [calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calvinism) and [reformed-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-theology) exist, but should probably be merged. I read [this blog post today](http://proofofgrace.com/naming-the-new-calvinism/) which shows the difference between calvinism and reformed theology. The author actually recommends calling it Dortism! I wouldn't, no one else calls it that. But when you look at what has been tagged with both tags they're almost all about soteriology. So reformed-theology would be better, or perhaps even [reformed-soteriology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-soteriology)! Perhaps a [reformed-sacraments](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-sacraments) tag could be made for the other parts of Calvinism/reformed theology...

http://proofofgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140610-160806-58086154.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[mathew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathew) is a misspelling of [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew). All questions tagged as [matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matthew) seem to refer to the [gospel-of-matthew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-matthew), not to the gospel's author, so both tags (Mathew and Matthew) should probably be synonyms for the gospel one.

Comment: When there's only two questions tagged with a mispelled tag it's easiest just to edit them and the bad tag will quickly disappear.

Answer (score -5):

I suggest making [ethics](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) a synonym of [morality](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality).

Comment: They *are* similar, but distinct enough that they shouldn't be synonyms.