# Why are there different tags for communion and eucharist?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonym suggestions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/tag-synonym-suggestions)

Why are there different tags for communion and eucharist? I guess I don't know whether they are different. I always thought they were just different names for the same thing.

Comment: Because no one has voted to accept my tag synonym!!

Answer (score 2):

This tag issue has already been brought up in [this answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/tag-synonym-suggestions/231#231) to another thread. We just need a moderator to start implementing some of those.

There is one context that `eucharist` is different than `communion` but I don't think we've considered it important. I believe the term can be used specifically to refer to the host (the bread?) as opposed to the overall celebration of the sacrament. For the purpose of tagging, I don't think it's distinction we need to make.