# What is the 'reformed-theology' tag about?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I saw [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/31118/20) was tagged as [reformed-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-theology) and though "Gee, that has nothing to do with Calvinism, let me remove that tag."<sup>*</sup>  But then I saw the wiki tag:

> The body of teaching which arose during and shortly after The Reformation

That description makes me think of "protestant theology" in general--in which case the tag may belong on that question.

But further consideration of the wiki description leaves me wondering, does it really mean "The body of teaching" in the sense of "all protestant teaching" or, "the body of teaching known as Reformed Theology"?

In any case... what is this tag really about?  Is it about Calvinist theology? My quick survey of questions with this tag make me think so. If it is, should the tag be made a synonym of [calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calvinism)?  If it's not about Calvinism, what is it about? How should the tag wiki be clarified?

<sup>*I see the final paragraph of the question says *"If this is scoped too broadly, let me apply it specifically to those denominations in the Reformed tradition"* which actually makes that tag appropriate, but I think this question still stands</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*([These tags have been discussed previously...](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3661/6071))*

For 90% of cases these tags are effectively synonymous. I would recommend making [calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calvinism) a synonym of [reformed-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-theology) however as the second is probably the more academic term. Also, the movement probably began before Calvin through people such as Zwingli. Secondly many denominations and churches use the label Reformed, but fewer use the label Calvinist. ("Reformed Baptist" is a common label for example.)

The tag wiki definitely needs editing. As confusing as it is, Reformed Theology definitely does not refer to all theology from the protestant reformation. *Edit*: I have suggested some tag wiki edits.

Comment: Good information. I wonder if you might copy/move the information from your linked answer to this one, since that other question was recently closed, and it certainly all applies here.

Comment: @Flimzy I've changed my mind since then, and this answer represents my current opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Reformed Theology is a subset of Protestant Theology that sits between Lutheranism on its left and Anabaptism on its right. It is basically Calvinistic, and has many adherents even today.

Answer (score 0):

Reformed theology typicalny includes the main points of Calvinism but is quite a bit broader category. At the same time it's quite a bit narrower than all of Protestantism. It's definitely something to have a unique tag for, although it sounds like the tag wiki could use some help.