# How do I make a tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I was reading quite a few questions today and something I noticed was the tag [wesleyanism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wesleyanism). Although I immediately understood it, it would not have entered my mind to call it that - I would have called it methodism ([methodist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodist)) as this is the commonly used word for all things relating the the churches set up around Wesley's principles. It is only a matter of time before someone tags this so I thought I'd pre-emptively make a tag synonym but then I couldn't figure out how to do it.

How do I make a tag synonym? Do I have insufficient reputation to complete this task? If so can someone else make it?

Comment: Wesleyan and Methodist *are* distinct denominations, though they do share a lot of principals

Comment: My understanding is that [Wesleyans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesleyanism) are a type of Methodist. Do you mean that the wesleyanism tag is meant for the wesleyan denomination?

Comment: I would've thought it was the other way round, Methodists are a type of Wesleyans.

Comment: That is, rather embarrassingly, what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need five rep in a tag to suggest a synonym. Three other people who also have five rep then vote on it in a hidden place of the site which they probably won't see. On smaller sites like this it's almost impossible to get synonyms approved.

Mods can more easily make synonyms, but most of the time synonyms aren't worth dealing with. Instead just retag all the relevant questions. But first get some community consensus on Meta that it's a good idea. For example [I'm still waiting to get enough support](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3856/6071) to turn [calvinism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calvinism) into [reformed-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformed-theology).